# UnityEngine.UI not working, ive tried a lot of fixes but im still getting this error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

> The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is the error I'm getting, I've got thousands of errors in my project because of this

note: im using Unity 2020.2.1f1 and i cannot upgrade off of this

Ive tried reinstalling the package, regenerating the solution, reloading all the assets, deleting the local repo and reinstalling it (no one else on the project has this issue), checked manifest.json and it has the correct line ("com.unity.modules.ui": "1.0.0",), ive had a look through my .csjproj files and I think it looks correct, the dll is installed in my editor

anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

edit:
having a similar issue with TextMeshPro,
not getting an error with "using TMPro" but I'm getting errors with TMP_Dropdown and TMP_InputField for example

Comment: Do you have this error on Unity side or only in the IDE (Visual Studio) ?

Comment: @derHugo I believe its only in the IDE? how would I know if its in the unity side too?

Comment: Unity console will show the errors

Comment: if it is only the IDE then you did something wrong in the installation or the way you open your script files (double click within Unity) ...

Comment: ive been opening it via the unity inspector, still getting these errors :(

Comment: It happens to me once.. and there was some IT magic that was interfering with Unity.
if you are using a company computer maybe ask the IT guy. ?

Comment: hmm it works fine on all other projects that I work on and they are set up the same